# Get DeviceToken For Push Notifications after logout and login again?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have done the process of getting the device token and storing it in userdefaults.For the first time login its working perfectly.And when the user logout and came back to login again the device token is nil. I want to call the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken in LoginViewController to get the device token.

Comment: You can save user's device token where you are storing user's other information like email and password. You can update the device token every time user logs in to the app.

Comment: Why would you nil the token when a user logs out?  You have to tell your APN service to not associate the token with the logged-out user, but the token doesn't change on the device when a user logs out of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try to use NSUserDefaults to store this data.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:deviceTokenString forKey:@"deviceToken"];
```

And to get this data use:

```
NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
NSString *string = [data objectForKey:@"deviceToken"];
```

**Note: You don't remove key @"deviceToken" from USER DEFAULT at logout time.**